# Writing a function to check the closeness of the strings

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am writing a function which will check the closeness of 2 strings. What I mean by closeness is:
strings "bat" and "bot" are 1 character apart, so the function should return 1. strings "dog" and "bot" are 2 characters apart, so the function should return 2(the 'd' vs 'b' and the 'g' vs 't'). strings "very good boy john" and "very good bot john" are just 1 character apart.
The length of 2 strings will always be the same.
I was not getting the desired output .My code for the following was:

```
int main(){
    string a = "dog";
    string b = "bot";
    int index = 0;
    int tot = std::count_if(a.begin(), a.end(), [&](char ch){
                                if(ch != b[index]){return true;}
                                return false;
                                index+=1;
                            });
    std::cout << tot; //expected 2 but not getting 2 :(
}
```

Any help?

Comment: Tip: `return ch != b[index]` and don't cast a boolean to a boolean.

Comment: I think your `index += 1` is being left out in the cold since you always `return` first. Consider `b[index++]` This code will also go into undefined behaviour unless string `b` is at least the length of string `a`.

Comment: See [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) which is more or less the count of edit steps to turn one string into the other.

Comment: Worth writing up a self-answer with the repaired code since you were able to test and confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to `b[index++]`
.Because the `index+=1` is not getting executed.

Answer (score 0):

A different algorithm does the work for you.

(untested)

```cpp
int main(){
    string a = "dog";
    string b = "bot";
    int tot = std::inner_product(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), 0,
                                std::plus<>(), std::not_equal_to<>());
    std::cout << tot; 
}
```

Requires that a and b are equal length or a is shortest

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
// Function to count the valid indices pairs
int pairs(string str1, int size1, string str2, int size2){
   // f1 and f2 for frequencies of characters
   // of string str1 and str2
   int f1[26] = { 0 };
   int f2[26] = { 0 };
   // 'c' To count the valid pairs
   int i, c = 0;
   //updating the frequencies of str1 and st2
   for (i = 0; i < size1; i++){
      f1[str1[i] - 'a']++;
   }
   for (i = 0; i < size2; i++){
      f2[str2[i] - 'a']++;
   }
   // Find the count of valid pairs
   for (i = 0; i < 26; i++){
      c += (min(f1[i], f2[i]));
   }
   return c;
}
// main function
int main(){
   string str1 = "tutorialspoint", str2 = "codingground";
   int size1 = str1.length(), size2 = str2.length();
   cout<<”Total pairs with str1[i]=str2[j] are: ”;
   cout << pairs(str1, size1, str2, size2);
   return 0;
}
```

Reference : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/count-common-characters-in-two-strings-in-cplusplus